# Make Child ViewGroup match parent height RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a RecyclerView item layout where a child viewgroup should match the height of the item its in so for example, I have a 250dp height item and I have a LinearLayout whose height is set to `match_parent` its height should also be 250dp.

This does not seem to be the case when I try to do this, the LinearLayout height seems to be forced to `wrap_content`

this is my example layout I am using to test with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ll"
            android:background="@color/android_green">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/android_red">

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I only see the LinearLayout when I set a hard height (250dp), if I change it to match_parent it disappears.

Is this not possible anymore with RecyclerView?

Comment: can you elaborate a little more what problem you are facing?

Comment: @subrahmanyamboyapati the linear layout is mot matching the height of the cell it always just the height of the content

Comment: `RelativeLayout` is a pain sometimes, especially when nesting. Try setting the `LinearLayout`'s `layout_alignParentTop` and `layout_alignParentBottom` attributes both to `true`.

Comment: @MikeM. yup tried that and what happens is the view does not stay aligned to the top and only to the bottom oddly enough

Comment: Just noticed you've got a `RelativeLayout` there that's not really doing anything. Have you tried removing that one? (The second one in.) The problems with nested `RelativeLayout`s usually come from the adjustments they make to themselves when doing their layout passes, so the fewer, the better, usually.

Comment: Why are you setting 'wrap_content' on your parent (root) RelativeLayout's height? Shouldn't this layout match the height of the recycler-view cell?

Comment: @Mdlc you are required to use wrap_content for the root layout container, if you dont each cell will be the height of the screen

Comment: Your root layout uses wrap_content while the child is using match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

You say you expect it to be 250dp right? Thing is, your LinearLayout is inside the secondary (2nd Order) RelativeLayout. Setting a match_parent will get it to copy the height from there instead of the 3rd Order RelativeLayout for which you have HardCoded 250dp.

I suggest keeping it so and scaling it in your java so your app can work across all devices... HardCoding numbers isn't really the best thing to do... However, if you **DO** need it to be exactly 250dp, make the LinearLayout a child of the 3rd Order RealativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ll"
            android:background="@color/android_green">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/ll"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/android_red">
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

I completely agree with Mike M.'s comment about removing the 2nd Order RelativeLayout. It's not serving any apparent purpose (at least not in the provided code) and uselessly complicating your program. If you DO need it, try to maybe look for alternative layouts that aren't so messy.

Answer (score 0):

can you explain the problem you are facing? If you have the given below problem ,then change to it as below.

please change your parent layout(LinearLayout's parent) ie, Relative layout height to 250dp, now it is match_parent, so you will get both layout size same as 250dp.
here below put the changed code, your intention is like it, then change it to

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ll"
        android:background="@color/color_dark_yellow">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/color_green_txt">

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can below approach to make child view group match parent height:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_child"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ll"
            android:background="#00FF00">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rl_child"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```